# Topic level session.timeout.ms

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two different topics in my kafka, but I would like the timeout for one my topics to be much higher than the other.

Is it possible to set a different values of `session.timeout.ms` for different topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**session.timeout.ms** is a consumer property, that the amount of time a consumer can be out of contact with the brokers while still considered alive defaults to 3 seconds.

This can be set at broker/consumer config level. So, if you are setting at broker level (defaults to 3), it will be applicable for all consumers and if you are overriding with consumer configuration (**ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG**), then it will be applicable for that particular consumer only.

The consumer will never timeout to any topics it is subscribed to, but it is a mere dead/alive decisioning property between the consumer and the broker.

> If more than session.timeout.ms passes without the consumer sending a
> heartbeat to the group coordinator, it is considered dead and the
> group coordinator will trigger a rebalance of the consumer group to
> allocate partitions from the dead consumer to the other consumers in
> the group.